# 'sh: 1: /usr/bin/xauth: Input/output error' error when trying to connect to school's server

Tags: server

I'm trying to connect school's server but it gives following error at opening:

```
sh: 1: /usr/bin/xauth: Input/output error
```

It does still connect to the server and I can change directories, but I can't open any program such as nano. That gives the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gnome-open: Input/output error
```

Can anyone help with this error?